# How to reload page in javascript after an alert in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, reload, ecmascript-5

I'm running through the MDN canvas game tutorial of the game Breakout.  When the ball passes the paddle, the game should end and the page reload, starting again.

The code looks like this:

```
 if (y + dy < ballRadius) {
     dy = -dy;
 } else if(y + dy > canvas.height-ballRadius) {
     if(x > paddleX && x < paddleX + paddleWidth) {
        dy = -dy;
     } else {
        alert("GAME OVER");
        document.location.reload();
     }
 }
```

In FireFox and Safari this runs as expected, after dismissing the alert, the page reloads and the script starts over from beginning.

However, in Chrome, after the the ball hits the end of the `y` bounds of the canvas and the alert is displayed, if you hit `Ok` to dismiss it, the page does not appear to reload.  Instead, the ball continues to move and after every iteration, a new alert is displayed (which if you dismiss with `Ok` it continues without reload).

Anyone have any idea what's happening and why the page will not reload?

[Here's the full code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Tutorials/2D_Breakout_game_pure_JavaScript/Game_over#Compare_your_code)

The same functionality as in Chrome can be observed in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/end3r/z4zy79fo/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=z4zy79fo)

> Update: In the console in Chrome, if I try `document.location.reload()` I get `undefined`.  `document.location` results in `localhost` as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear the interval after you call the reload.

Change `setInterval(draw, 10);` to `var interval = setInterval(draw, 10);`.

Add `clearInterval(interval);` after `document.location.reload();`.

Comment: This worked, thanks.  Could you elaborate a little more on what's going on here?   Obviously, you're telling it to stop the event loop, but not sure if there's any rational behind why Chrome functions in this manner.

Comment: I made your code into a separate page to to debug it. When the game ends the window gets stuck in the reload (shown by the spinner) so I think that in Chrome an alert is allowed to block the page from reloading but in other browsers it is not.